# How to find element with ID thats constantly changing in cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have a problem with an element thats ID is constantly changing (dynamic) and its only difference from other element is only the ID. How can I .find() it? Appreciate all the help, Im new to cypress
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOQuo.png)

Note that there is other element that is identical to this one but has other id

Comment: Add the code and the html showing the id in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `*` with the part of the id, that is constant, something like this:

```js
cy.get('[id*="upload-ChooseFile"]').eq(0)
```

Comment: then it finds 2 elements because they are the same, only difference between them is ID which is dynamic

Comment: You can add `eq(0)` for the first element or `eq(1)` for the second element. Updated the answer.

Comment: Do you have html of other returned element?

Comment: thanks @AlapanDas I used the eq() method